# JavaScript username and password verification

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am trying to take a username and password as input and if the entered username and password are admin admin I want to forward them to a new php file. I dont understand where I am going wrong. Any help. Thank you in advance

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    window.alert("called");
var user=document.getelementbyId(log).value;
var pass=document.getelementbyId(password).value;
window.alert("stored");
if((user=="admin")&&(pass="admin"))
{
    window.alert("logging");
    window.location.href='edusculpt_admin.php';
    }
else
    window.alert("Username or Password Incorrect");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Admin Login</h3>
<form method="post">
    <p>
        Login ID: <input type="text" id="log" value=""
            placeholder="Username or Email">
    </p>
    <p>
        Password: <input type="password" id="password" value=""
            placeholder="Password">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if((user=="admin")&&(pass="admin"))` should be `if((user=="admin")&&(pass=="admin"))`

Comment: It seems like you are taking on a bit more than you can chew.  Perhaps you should seek out paid help.  Handling user/password information in open script is a bad idea.  Using the front-end to handle the routing that the back-end should be doing is also a bad idea.  Before you jump in head first by implementing a log-in system, try to take some baby steps and learn the language.  For instance, learn how JS interacts with HTML and coding styles and best practices.

Comment: I feel that someone should point out that checking any username / password on the client side is an absolutely horrible idea. If this is supposed to provide any level of security it is practically useless. *Always, always* do authentication on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive, `getelementbyId` should be `getElementById` and id's needs to be wrapped in quotes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validate()
{
    window.alert("called");
    var user=document.getElementById('log').value;
    var pass=document.getElementById('password').value;
    window.alert("stored");
    if((user=="admin")&&(pass=="admin"))
    {
        window.alert("logging");
        window.location.href='edusculpt_admin.php';
    }
    else
        window.alert("Username or Password Incorrect");
}
</script>
```

Also Note, You have submit button in your form .. which is not handled in `validate` function, either you can make `<input type="button" ...` or handle event in `validate` method.

Answer (score 0):

`getelementbyId` should be `getElementById` & enclose the ID name by quote

```
var user=document.getElementById("log").value;
var pass=document.getElementById("password").value;
```

And compare by `==` instead of `=`

```
if((user=="admin")&&(pass=="admin"))
                         ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

change `onclick="validate()"` to `onclick="return validate();"`.

this way, when validate returns false, the form won't click. you'd also have to change the validate func to return false when the form doesn't validate, the resulting code would be:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>
    User Validation  : 2nd Program
    </title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

   function validate()
    {
    alert(form.username.value)
    alert(document.getelementbyId(username).value);
    alert(form.password.value)
        if(form.username.value == "sample" && form.password.value =="password")
            {
                alert("User Validated ");
                return true;
            }
        else
            {
                alert("Incorrect Username or Password" );
                return false;
            }

    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <h3>Admin Login</h3>
<form method="post">
    <p>
        Login ID: <input type="text" id="log" value=""
            placeholder="Username or Email">
    </p>
    <p>
        Password: <input type="password" id="password" value=""
            placeholder="Password">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="validate()">
</form>
</body>
    </text>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   function validate()
    {
    alert(form.username.value)
    alert(document.getelementbyId(username).value);
    alert(form.password.value)
        if(form.username.value == "sample" && form.password.value =="password")
            {
                alert("User Validated ");
                return true;
            }
        else
            {
                alert("Incorrect Username or Password" );
                return false;
            }

    }
    </script>
```

Update: continue and break illustrated.

```
while(true) {
    // :loopStart
    var randomNumber = Math.random();
    if (randomNumber < .5) {
        continue; //skips the rest of the code and goes back to :loopStart
    }
    if (randomNumber >= .6) {
        break; //exits the while loop (resumes execution at :loopEnd)
    }
    alert('value is between .5 and .6');
}
// :loopEnd
```